# Java - NodeList can't get Childnode

Tags: java, xml, dom, nodelist

I don't understand how to get child node parsing xml file with java. For example I have this code:

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class Parser {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try{
            File stocks = new File("Stocks.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(stocks);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();



            NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("stock");
            Node nodez = nodes.item(1);
            String s = nodez.getFirstChild().getNodeName(); //outputs #text?
                        System.out.println(s);
                        //If I try this
                        String s = nodez.getNodeName(); //outputs 'stock'


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



}
```

So if I try to output current node name, it outputs properly, but if I try to output next child node name, it just outputs #text.
How can I properly output any node I want? I thought I could just use method as `getFirstChild` or `getNextSibling`, but it seems I'm doing something wrong?

You can find xml file using this link:

http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/12/parse-xml-file-in-java-example-tutorial.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Element "stock" contains text, which is returned as first child. You can use folloving:

```
        System.out.println(((Element) nodez).getElementsByTagName("symbol").item(0).getNodeName());
        // get all nodes
        NodeList nl=((Element) nodez).getElementsByTagName("*");
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            System.out.println(nl.item(i).getNodeName());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the [node type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html) of the actual node.

`#text` is also a node! but you are probably looking for the type `Element`

Get the node list from your document using [Document#getElementsByTagName](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#getElementsByTagName%28java.lang.String%29) and iterate over it. Check the type of each node to identify the ones you are interested in.